# How to center multiple divs even after window size changes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the divs always be centered even after one div drops to the bottom if window size is adjusted. So basically if there are 5 divs and one drops to the bottom after window size reached a certain point, so the remaining 4 divs would still be centered. If possible it would be better if the one dropped wouldn't center but be on the left.

```css
.item-holder {
    width: 95%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: teal;
}

.item {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.item-text {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-holder">
    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 4</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 5</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 6</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 7</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 8</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 9</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 10</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[How the result should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTPLR.jpg)

Comment: Use flexbox. Add `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` to your container. Remove the float: left. Play around with flexbox, is fairly easier with what you're trying to accomplish: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Remove the overflow: scroll, Im guessing you want overflow-y: scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use CSS Grid Layout

CSS Grid was like made for this purpose. In the following snippet, I have removed some of your lines and resized the children. But you need to **pay attention to the three lines of code added to `.item-holder`.**
I have also made the holder resizable, so you can play with it.

```css
.item-holder {
  width: 95%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: teal;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 5px;
  
  /* Following code makes the element resizable*/
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

.item-text {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-holder">
  <div class="item">
    <p class="item-text">Item 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <p class="item-text">Item 2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <p class="item-text">Item 3</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <p class="item-text">Item 4</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <p class="item-text">Item 5</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <p class="item-text">Item 6</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <p class="item-text">Item 7</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <p class="item-text">Item 8</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <p class="item-text">Item 9</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <p class="item-text">Item 10</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Further Reading

- See [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) on MDN
- Learn CSS Grid Layout on [freeCodeCamp.org](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/responsive-web-design/css-grid/)
- See CSS Grid Layout: Create flexible layouts using auto-fill on [freeCodeCamp.org](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/responsive-web-design/css-grid/create-flexible-layouts-using-auto-fill)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `.item-holder` a flexbox

```css
.item-holder {
    width: 95%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: teal;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.item-text {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-holder">
    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 4</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 5</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 6</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 7</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 8</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 9</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item-text">Item 10</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think he needs `flex-wrap: wrap`

Comment: Yeah. I suggested the combined `flex-flow` property. `flex-flow: row wrap;`